# Initialize Managed Bean from view

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am having a really difficult time dealing with what Scope I should use on my application.

I am using Primefaces using a  for my initial view layout. Outside of the layout I have dialogs that are used by many different managed beans.

Within my layout I have a header, footer a navgiation on the left and then the current view in the center. So my view looks as follows:

```
<h:body id=body">
   <p:layoutUnit id=head" position="top">
         <ui:insert name="header">
   </p:layoutUnit>
   <p:layoutUnit id=head" position="bottom">
         <ui:insert name="footer">
   </p:layoutUnit>
   <p:layoutUnit id=head" position="left">
         <ui:insert name="menu">
   </p:layoutUnit>
   <p:layoutUnit id=head" position="right">
         <ui:insert name="main">
   </p:layoutUnit>

   <p:dialog widgetVar="addAddressDialog" header="Add New Address">
       <h:form id="insertAddress">
            <h:inputText id="insert_address" label="Address" />
       </h:form>
   </p:dialog>

   <p:dialog widgetVar="updateAddressDialog" header="Add New Address">
       <h:form id="updateAddress">
            <h:inputText id="update_address" value=#{addressBean.selectedAddress.address" />
       </h:form>
   </p:dialog>
```

The issue I am having is when my application first loads the addressBean's @PostConstruct is getting called because the view is being loaded. In the @PostConstruct I initialize the list of addresses associated to an specific id called contactId. At this point though the contactId has not been instantiated. That happens once he user interacts with the "main" view.

My Scope for the addressBean is currently @ViewScope which works find but only for the first time that the contactId is set. After that it continues to retain the information that was populated even if the contactId changes because the @PostConstruct is never called again and the view never seems to go out of scope.

I have tried @RequestScope and this works actually really well. But I run into a problem when displaying the addresses in a datatable inside the "main" view. I have a button at the bottom of my datatable that called the insertAddressDialog.show(). It opens the first time and I can insert the data but 1. The view the datatable never shows the new record that I have inserted because I guess the view has been lost at that point. And 2. The button on the datable is no longer alive or active, so the dialog wont open after the first time a user inserts a record.

This seems like this should be an easy thing but my application has many nested views which is causing the problem. Any insight on how to handle something like this would really be a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really sound like a PrimeFaces issue.

The ViewScoped bean will remain in scope as long as you do not navigate away from the page (view) to which it is associated.  The RequestScoped bean will re-instantiate every time you interact with it.  If you're trying to store variables into the RequestScoped bean on one interaction, then update a database with those variables on a second interaction, the second interaction will re-instantiate the bean and you're variables will be gone (okay, the variables are still there - its the values that disappear).

Do you have a compelling reason for using @PostConstruct to initialize addresses? It sounds like you have a main page where users start to interact with the program, from that main page the user enters (or the program otherwise retrieves) the user's contactId.  This contactId variable is used to populate a data table showing all addresses associated with that user's contactId.  It sounds like the error is in your bean logic.

You need to get the contactId first, then use that to fill the data table.  I don't know how your program/user interacts with the bean to provide the contactId.  If the contactId is input from the user, then don't initialize the address list in @PostConstruct because it will always be initialized before the contactId is entered.  If the program is obtaining the contactId automatically from, say, a variable of type user (which it knows about because the user signed in and the program created/retrieved the user's contactId from the database), you should be able to include that code in @PostConstruct - before the data table is initialized.

Or, instead of using @PostConstruct, simply include a method call in your web page at a point ***before*** your page (view) references any variables.  You can just put the method call right on the page:

#{myBean.myMethod}
      
          Other code here...

The bean should be called and constructed before you get to the method call, and your user's contactId should be available for the bean's data manipulation. (I'm making an assumption on that last point since we can't see your bean logic.)

Comment: "You can just put the method call right on the page:

#{myBean.myMethod} Other code here..." That is one idea I did not think of but this does not work for me. Your assumption about how my program works is right. I just need a way to instantiate the bean before the view is loaded or at the top of the view like you suggested.

Comment: I could put login in the getter of my datatable list such as if(address == null) { myDao.getAddresses(); return addresses } else { return addresses} but I was undert he assumption that no logic should ever go in setters and getters.

Comment: Okay, your bean is instantiated before the view is loaded. That's what is giving you problems, the bean is instantiated (constructed) then immediately the @PostConstruct is being called. You need to initialize your data table after passing the contactId to your bean.  You could also just set your contactId in @PostConstruct, especially since it already exists prior to instantiating your bean, then initialize your datatable in @PostConstruct.  Your issue is just logic flow.